# Как считать символ с мультибайтовой строки?

Tags: c, utf-8

Есть мультибайтовая строка, длина её меряется в мегабайтах, нужно считывать в цикле посимвольно, как считать один символ с мультибайтовой строки?(не используя uchar.h)

Comment: Да unicode codepoint.

Comment: Глянул википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8  в общем ничего особо сложного. проверяете первый символ, если 4 старших бита `1` - берете еще 3 байта. _Иначе_, если 3 - то 2, _иначе_ если 2 - то 1. А вот если старший бит есть и следующий за ним бит `0` - то дела плохи, вы каким то образом оказались в середине символа. Вопрос лишь в том, что дальше с символами делать, если надо получить их нормальные коды, то еще поработать с битами придется

Comment: Википедию первым делом и прочитал, принцип кодирования понял но я мягко говоря не особо хорошо умею работать с байтами, декодировать и т.п. думал есть готовые варинаты, которые получше моих велосепедов.

Comment: Если не хотите своих велосипедов, то читайте [man mbsrtowcs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbsrtowcs.3.html) и [man mbrtowc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbrtowc.3.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Берем очередной байт из строки. Предполагая, что это первый байт utf-8 символа

```
unsigned char b=...; // тут проверяемый байт (обязательно unsigned !!!)
if(b<=0x7F) это однобайтовый символ, можем выдавать его и проверять следующий
else if(b>=0xF8) ... это не unicode символ, или более новый стандарт с более чем 4х байтовыми символами
else if(b>=0xF0) ... это 4х байтовый символ. т.е. берем еще следующие 3 байта
else if(b>=0xE0) ... это 3х байтовый символ. т.е. берем еще следующие 2 байта
else if(b>=0xC0) ... это 2х байтовый символ. т.е. берем еще следующий байт
else ... b - совершенно точно один из серединных байт символа, мы потеряли первый байт
```

Если символ длиной более 1 байта, то все последующие байты символа *должны* быть в диапазоне `b>=0x80 && b<0xC0`

Написал по стандарту [RFC3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), надеюсь нигде не ошибся. Можно еще посмотреть код готовых библиотек.

Эх. Обожаю делать велосипеды, вот накидал пример, с разбором кодов символов. Получаемые коды для русских букв сверил с выдаваемых функцией `Javascript charCodeAt` - совпали. Внимание: собрано на коленке. нет проверок, что строка закончилась в середине символа, при неправильной unicode строке возможен выход за пределы массива ! Трехбайтные и четырехбайтные символы так же не проверены, т.к. не знаю китайского. Так же нет проверки 2го и последующего байта unicode на корректность, тупо сбрасываем старшие 2 бита и используем.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char *s="Test string. Тестовая строка";
int main()
 {
  int len=strlen(s);
  int i;
  int sim_code; // Сюда собираем код очередного символа
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
    if(s[i]<=0x7F)      { sim_code=s[i]; }
    else if(s[i]>=0xF8) { printf("Не unicode 6.0 (RFC3629) символ %X",s[i]); continue; }
    else if(s[i]>=0xF0) { sim_code=( ((s[i]&0x07)<<18) | ((s[i+1]&0x3F)<<12) | ((s[i+2]&0x3F)<<6) | (s[i+3]&0x3F) ); i+=3; }
    else if(s[i]>=0xE0) { sim_code=( ((s[i]&0x0F)<<12) | ((s[i+1]&0x3F)<<6) | (s[i+2]&0x3F) ); i+=2; }
    else if(s[i]>=0xC0) { sim_code=( ((s[i]&0x1F)<<6) | (s[i+1] & 0x3F) ); i++; }
    else { printf("Пропущен первый байт unicode символа !!! (%X)",s[i]); continue; }
    printf("%d ",sim_code);
   }
 }
```

Универсальный способ получения длины текущего символа:

```
unsigned char b=s[i]; // Берем первый байт символа
int n; // длина символа
if(b<=0x7F) n=1; ... это однобайтовый символ, работаем с ним как есть
else
 for(n=0; b & 0x80; n++) b<<=1;
 // после цикла n=полной длине в байтах, включая текущий байт
```

Comment: @Виталий, кое-что полезное по этой теме можно посмотреть в [ucsutf.c](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW) и [ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL)

Comment: Спасибо, смысл понял, погуглю ещё немного "utf-8 decode" и т.п. и думаю уже выстроется единая картинка в голове.

Comment: @Виталий Обновил ответ, написал рабочий пример

Comment: С трёхбайтовыми работает прекрасно, ну, а четыхбайтные мне не нужны. Буду дальше эксперементировать, спасибо.

Comment: Вообще-то utf-8 позволяет кодировать в 6 байтах все целые до 2^31. Я бы не стал сразу делать проверку на < 0xF8

Comment: @avp Ok. Я усилил оговорку на "более новый стандарт" :) Хотя тут недавно видел реализацию base64 плагинчик к jQuery, так там даже 4х байтовые не учитываются.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, есть встроенные функции для работы с UTF8. А при чём тут base64 я вообще не понял, т. к. ему вообще кодировка без разницы.

Comment: @Qwertiy это я к слову сказал, что даже 4х байтовые многие не учитывают. просто в JS большие проблемы с побайтной работой с utf-8, строенные в современные браузеры функции типа `atob` вообще его не поддерживают. А Виталия интересовало именно как оно работает, поэтому он в вопросе и указал "не используя uchar.h"

Comment: @Виталий Я добавил в ответ простой способ получения длины символа в байтах

Comment: Да, невнимательно прочитал. Откуда вообще utf8 в js? `btoa` работает со строкой как с массивом байтов, т. е. 256 возможных значений в символе. Если там реально текст, то надо превращать в utf16 руками.

Comment: @Qwertiy В том то и проблема, что в JS строка всегда в utf-8. И если мы пытаемся реализовать любой алгоритм работающий побайтно то упираемся в то, что при добавлении к строке 1 байта >= 0x80 получаем добавленные 2 байта, т.к. JS пытается таким образом сохранить формат строки. Библиотеки которые хотят менять кодировки решают эту проблему весьма замысловато, типа пересчитывая двухбайтные представления и подменяя более длинные. И попробуй сделать btoa("Привет") например в хроме, получишь большой привет от браузера. Я когда base85 на JS делал вообще через decodeURI пошел, что бы строку собрать

Comment: @Mike, строки в js (как и везде) в utf16, а не в utf8.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ok, буду иметь ввиду. И что значит "как и везде" я вижу как сервера отлично отдают UTF-8 и там латинские символы однобайтные. И как то UTF-16 на стороне серверов вообще не принят. Да те же html де факто все в UTF-8... И в JS все равно btoa с русским не работает, ни в какой кодировке :)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что большинство языков программирования используют utf16 для представления строк в памяти. А для передачи с сервера, да и просто для файлов - да, utf8 уже почти стандарт.

Answer (score 1):

Вот незамысловатая функция, которую можно использовать в своей программе на C/C++ для определения "размера символа" закодированного в UTF-8.

```
/*
  Проверяет является ли байт началом символа в UTF-8
  Возвращает
  -1 - недопустимый символ 
  n > 0 UTF-8 символ длиной n байт
 */
int
utf8_chrlen (const char *utf)
{
  unsigned int ucs = *utf & 0xFF;

  if (ucs < 128)
    return 1;
  if ((ucs & 0xC0) == 0x80 || ucs == 0xFF || ucs == 0xFE)
    return -1;

  int n = 5;
  while (n && (ucs & (1<<n)))
    n--;
  return 7-n;
}
```