# Как сравнить несколько бит данных?

Tags: c, binary

Имеется байт данных, в bin: 11010000, как можно проверить что первые 3 бита - 110?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из многих путей:

```
(bin >> 5) & 7 == 6
```

Что происходит:

1. Сдвигаем нужные биты влево

   ```
   xxxxxxxx11010000 // было
   xxxxxxxxxxxxx110 // стало
   ```
2. Применяем маску, которая вытащит только нужные биты:

   ```
   xxxxxxxxxxxxx110 // было
                111 // маска
   0000000000000110 // стало
   ```
3. Результат сравниваем с нужной комбинацией бит (бинарное 110 — это 6).

---

Обычно вам не должно хотеться сравнивать биты вручную, это слишком низкоуровневая операция. Для таких штук часто лучше приспособлены битовые поля:

```
struct Data
{
    unsigned int p1 : 3; // первые три бита
    unsigned int p2 : 1; // следующий 1 бит
    unsigned int p3 : 4; // следующие 4 бита
};

Data data;
// ...
if (data.p1 == 6)
{
```

Здесь все сдвиги сделает за вас компилятор.

Comment: &7 можно и не использовать, оно байт по условию задачи.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Это да, но я на случай, если ТС захочет обобщить код, выбирая биты в середине байта. Ну или на случай более длинных данных.

Comment: @VladD А почему бы просто не `a & 0b11100000 == 0b110000001` ну или `a & 0xE0 == 0xC0` если вдруг `0b` не доступно.

Comment: @Mike: Для этого требуется шифтануть 0b110 влево, так что количество операций по идее то же. Ваш путь может быть предпочтительнее, если 0b110 — константа времени компиляции, и компилятор проведёт сдвиг в compile time. Но я же специально написал «Один из многих путей» :-)

Comment: @Vlad Ну разве что так. Я просто привык расценивать фразу 'проверить первые 3 бита' буквально. Плюс к этому ТС час назад спрашивал как своими силами узнать длину символов в UTF-8. А она кодируется как раз старшими битами первого байта и там константы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474663/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @Mike: И правда, это ТС сканирует символы UTF-8. Тогда ему нужны не битовые поля, а библиотека поддержки utf-8, и пусть не морочит себе голову.

Comment: Библиотеки это не интересно. Я си изучаю не для того чтоб юзать готовое, да и не люблю я чёрные ящики + мне всегда были такие вещи интересны.