# Как правильно обрабатывать 8-битные строки в Си/Lua?

Tags: c, строки, utf-8, lua, char

Пишу игру на Си и Lua. Возникает необходимость вывода текста на экран посредством библиотеки SDL_TTF. Нужно, чтобы программа могла дробить строку, если та слишком длинная (необходимо для переноса, чтобы текст поместился в окно).
Однако я сталкиваюсь со следующей проблемой: Lua кодирует символы в 8 бит, а любой кириллический символ программа видит как два, и длина строки увеличивается вдвое.
В Lua 5.3 есть utf8.len, которая корректно отобразит длину строки. Но мне это мало поможет, потому что мне нужно как-то пробежаться по строке, найти символ пробела, выделить из строки подстроку и т.д., чтобы корректно осуществить перенос выводимой строки на экране.
Как это сделать? Можно ли? Неважно, в Си или в Lua, но как?

Comment: пробел однобайтный (если не используются какие нибудь специальные utf пробельные символы), ищите его как обычно, например strchr() а потом с помощью вашей функции определения длины строки определяйте сколько символов до данного пробела. Хотя для C есть масса библиотек которые позволят легко работать с utf строкой посимвольно

Comment: Если вам не трудно, назовите, пожалуйста, пару примеров или подскажите направление, в котором нужно копать. Поскольку пробелы и знаки препинания однобайтные, то размер строки с кириллицей получается неоднородным.

Comment: Ну если велосипед делать, то можно бежать самому по строке и считать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474720/194569

Comment: Mike, большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Есть ещё boost (но это C++) с его UTF-8 регулярками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Lua 5.3, помимо `utf8.len`, есть [ещё несколько полезных функций для работы с utf8](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5).

Соответственно, чтобы пробежаться по символам utf8 строки, можно воспользоваться функцией `utf8.codes()`, которая последовательно возвращает позицию (в байтах) и числовое представление символа. Далее, это числовое представление символа можно легко сравнить с числовым представлением пробельного символа и выполнить какие-то действия над строкой.

Вот простая функция разделения строки на подстроки. В качестве разделителя принимается таблица. В данной функции так же используется стандартная функция `utf8.char()` которая переводит числовое представление символа обратно в utf8 строку.

```
local function utf8_split_max(str, sep, substr_max) 

  local i = 1 -- число подстрок
  local len = 0 -- длина текущей подстроки  
  local s = {} -- здесь будут накапливаться подстроки

  for _, c in utf8.codes(str) do -- итерация по символам строки         
      local found = false          
      if len >= substr_max then 
        for _, v in ipairs(sep) do -- итерация по разделителям
            if c == v then
              found = true  -- текущий символ - разделитель
              break
            end
        end
      end          
      if found then
        i = i + 1
        len = 0
      else
        if s[i] == nil then 
          s[i] = {} -- каждая подстрока - таблица чаров
        end
        table.insert(s[i], utf8.char(c))
        len = len + 1
      end
  end

  -- собираем чары в строки и возвращаем результат
  local r = {}
  for _, t in ipairs(s) do         
    table.insert(r, table.concat(t))  
  end
  return r
end
```

Пример использования:

```
-- код должен быть сохранён в файл, с кодировкой UTF-8
local s = 'Длинная юникодная строка'
local whitespace = {0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0x20, 0x85, 0xA0, 0x1680, 0x2000, 0x2001}

local substr = utf8_split_max(s, whitespace, 10)

for _, str in pairs(substr) do
  print(str)  
end
```

Comment: Это очень хороший пример, ещё и такой подробный. От всей души благодарю!